# Tabhost in all activities in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i am new in android and i have just used the tab host its working fine but now i want to use it in more than one activity so here what i tried for that

```
TabHost tabHost= getTabHost();

    //tabHost.setup();
     TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        photospec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Login.class);
        photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

        // Tab for Songs
        TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Songs");        
        songspec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_songs_tab));

        Intent songsIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Registration.class);
        songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

        // Tab for Videos
        TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
        videospec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
        Intent videosIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Login.class);
        videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
        tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
        tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab
```

And this is my xml code

```
  <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:baselineAligned="true" >
<TabHost 
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

its working fine in one activity but not in this one.

Comment: TabHost and TabWidget are now deprecated. Please use Action Bar and Fragments instead.

Comment: can you mention any tutorial or any guide ? @HardikTrivedi

Comment: Yea sure, you can start with http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbar-tab-listfragment-in-android.html and http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-action-items-from-within-fragments/